# File Upload not working in IE + ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using valums file_uploader.js to upload files & I wanted to upload all the type of files like images, audios, videos, etc. It is working very fine in firefox & chrome. In safari upload is working good except for multiple files. But in IE nothing is working.

There is one line input.files to fetch the file details. It is giving null or undefined in IE.
I tried all the versions of IE, 7-9. But no use.

How do I get the file properties in IE using javascript. I tried to use ajax-uploader, but I'm not getting how to use it.

I'm using ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2.1 & jquery 1.7.2. is it any problem with the versions?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did u solve this problem I am having the same......